# Is there a structured meritocracy outside of academia?

Tags: promotion, careers

I am an engineering PhD student in the "academic bubble". I have no personal connections to the industry and have little to no clue as to how it operates. One of the things that appeals to me most about academia is that it is largely meritocratic (at least as far as an institution this large can be) and linear - publish enough good work and you'll eventually move your way up the "ranks" to the top job - professorship.

I've heard off-hand that this is not the case in the industry - that a glass ceiling keeps the "top jobs" virtually out of reach unless well connected (usually nepotistically) and that there is a great deal of frustration with regards to the "job ladder" in general.

This seems overly cynical to me but as aforementioned I have no experience with the industry. So my interconnected questions are as follows:

What are the practical differences between promotions in academia and promotions in the industry? Are there differences in how much of a role "luck" or "connections" make? Are the paths to the "top jobs" as clearly defined as they are in academia? Will anybody motivated and competent enough make it to the top as often as they would in an academic setting?

Comment: Yes, in the open source or free software world.

Comment: What is your field?

Comment: @ImmortanJoe The ageism in tech is more a myth than anything else.  40+, never had a problem due to my age and most companies are anxious to get their hands on me for my experience.  Never seen or heard a verifiable tale of anyone else having the issue either.  Especially not at 30, that's not even old.

Comment: @ImmortanJoe The only problem is that around 30, you stop being an impressionably youth who can be exploited mercilessly, for example in the gaming industry. So yes, you won't get a job anymore where you just get exploited.

Comment: @Helena I am working in mechanical engineering/physics (fluid mechanics). The replies so far have been great, thanks.

Comment: @GabeSechan : you're not in France, obviously. good programmers get weeded out - as well as the bad ones - around 35/40 years old, over there. I had to switch to software quality to stay in the industry.

Answer (score 13):

Are connections important in industry? Absolutely. If you want to be a top executive, then you probably need some connections. But there is nothing stopping you going out and making those connections.

Are *family* connections important? Not any more. It may have been the case 50 years ago, but the world's moved on since then.

I also think you are dramatically underestimating the amount of "politics" that occurs in academia; "just publishing enough good work" won't get you to the top, you need to influence the right people just as you do in industry.

Comment: Without connections in academia you will struggle to get the grants to publish the good work in the first place hah, +1.

Comment: It's worth noting too that there have been significant attacks on academic careers since the heyday decades ago, and academia has (for better or worse) been made more akin to "industry", so they won't seem entirely dissimilar. The old distinction between academia and industry was not that either was more or less meritocratic, but that they had different standards of achievement. In industry, you are under pressure to generate profits for the firm, whereas academia was seen as a place to explore ideas and generate knowledge useful in general (not necessarily to any particular economic concern).

Comment: Locale, family, ethnicity and other factors can be much more important than competence in many places and it can also depend on the industries revenue stream. If the industries revenue stream is reliant on government or other local factors, then it's hugely different from one that is from competing in the market internationally. In some places this holds true even for academia, perhaps even more so. Having a professorship from some Uni's does not guarantee you can read and write, but it does guarantee you belong to one of a few families.

Answer (score 5):

Having worked in both academia and industry I can ASSURE you that industry is way more of a technical meritocracy than academia ! Academia has comparatively few checks and balances in terms of quality control and once someone is tenured, they can pretty much work on anything or nothing at all, regardless of whether it's useful, interesting to anyone else, or even factually correct in the first place.

Industry, at the end of the day, needs to make money. Products & services need to actually work and function, need to add value, and be sold to customers, and you can't talk your way out of something that's technically wrong.

Answer to your specific question from my personal experience (which is a single data point, so take it with a grain of salt).

> What are the practical differences between promotions in academia and promotions in the industry?

Industry: do good work, get patents, be able to work with other people and in a team, be a good leader, produce stuff that function's well, contribute to the bottom line. Academia: be good at get funding, write lots of papers (quantity matters, quality doesn't), know how to do politics in the department and administration, be at the right spot at the right time.

> Are there differences in how much of a role "luck" or "connections" make?

Academia typically requires way more politics and luck. Often you need to wait until someone vacates a position or a tenured chair. This can take MANY years. Industry is typically based on growth, so new opportunities happen more naturally.

> Are the paths to the "top jobs" as clearly defined as they are in academia?

Depends on the company but I have seen CEOs coming up both through the technical or the business track. There tends to be more flexibility in finding a mix between leadership and technical contribution that suites you personally.

> Will anybody motivated and competent enough make it to the top as often as they would in an academic setting?

What makes you think that motivated and competent people make it to the top in academia? There is extremely little movement at the top: my first boss kept his chair for 29 years and the number two guy is still there (ca. 40 years and counting). Most motivated and competent PhD that I know went to industry and had good careers there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised at parts of your question, academia is the last place I'd think of as meritocratic.  It's poisonously political, especially in liberal arts (maybe slightly less so in sciences, but still greatly prevalent).

The answer probably greatly depends on what field of engineering you're in-  software will be different than chemical engineering, will be different from civil engineering, etc.  But if you actually want to be an engineer-  not a manager or executive-  its less political and more about capability, although ability to get along with, help, and mentor juniors is needed at higher levels.  It also depends on working environment-  big companies are more political than small ones, although very small ones are more likely to have risks of nepotism.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't have a country tag, but for the UK, some data relevant to answering this question can be found in figure 1.1 of the [Milburn report](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/61090/IR_FairAccess_acc2.pdf).  The data suggest that having been born to higher-income parents is a relatively-small and decreasing advantage in entry to lecturer and professor roles in academia; and a relatively-large and increasing advantage in entry to the (industrial) engineering profession.

However, this is imperfect as an answer in several ways:

- the Milburn report is eight years old, and a great deal could have changed in that time;
- while using the data in a comparative manner, as above, goes some way to controlling out confounding variables, it is still not clear that all possible confounders have been properly controlled;
- this data-set doesn't consider other potentially-important forms of inequality, such as inequality by gender or ethnicity;
- the data don't come with any uncertainty estimates, so one can't assess whether the observed differences are statistically significant;
- the data-set only considers initial entry to the profession, not advancement within the profession.

As an aside, I invite OP to be careful with jargon: "meritocracy" is not the same thing as "fair equality of opportunity", and I suspect what OP really wanted to ask about was "fair equality of opportunity".

Answer (score 0):

**In industry, being good can be its own network (major caveat below)**

I am starting a new job in a few weeks. A former co-worker reached out to me for building her team as she liked my previous work. The job comes with a nice pay raise and more responsibility. I have had other past co-workers reach out about opportunities as well and I have pursued these to different lengths (not all were jobs, so they could be done concurrently). It is a regular thing, about once every two months or so.

I still had to pass an interview for this opportunity, but I was a fast-tracked favourite to have the job and they were willing to accept me despite me being well below the experience level they were originally seeking.

**The caveat to this:** You need to be visibly good and pleasant to work with. Your co-workers need to know that you can do good work. If you silently work in the corner, never talk to anyone, and nobody knows what you do, this will not work.

Basically half the people you work with should be saying "we want him" if they went to other companies and you applied for a job there. If not, you will need another strategy.

> What are the practical differences between promotions in academia and promotions in the industry?

The biggest difference is that you can easily port your skills elsewhere. Most people are not promoted internally and even when they are, they tend to earn less. They go and shop for the promotion elsewhere. It would be rare for a tenured professor to shop around universities for a raise. In industry, most people are doing that fairly regularly (not necessarily switching, but looking). Employees also have fewer protections from their companies. There is no corporate tenure except in family-owned businesses.

> Are there differences in how much of a role "luck" or "connections" make?

Varies all over industry and job function. Government has experience tables and rules, as do organizations like the military so at least the smaller promotions are based on time served and qualifications. So do some union jobs. In others, it can be a heavily word of mount business. There are plenty in between.